# How can I do multiple joins on multiple tables in an external database in access

Tags: inner-join, external-data-access

I have five related variables that I need to examine from three different external tables in the same database which will require two inner joins (I think).  I can't seem to put the external file ref in the right spot to make the syntax work.

Almost every permutation you can think of, and all have syntax errors. The sample below is the easiest to conceptually read to describe what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
   txntable1.AccountRef_FullName AS [GL Name], 
   txntable1.Amount AS [Bill Amount], 
   billtable1.Amount AS [Paid Amount], 
   billtable1.PayeeEntityRef_FullName AS Vendor, 
   billtable1.TxnDate AS [Check Date]

FROM 
   billtable1, linkedtable1, txntable1 
IN 
   'c:\Users\database.mdb' 

INNER JOIN 
   billtable1
ON 
   billtable1.TxnID = linkedtable1.TxnID
AND
INNER JOIN 
   linkedtable1
ON 
   linkedtable1.IDKEY = txntable1.IDKEY
```

Syntax error in FROM clause, even if "in" is moved to after each external table.

Comment: What database is this? Usually you do something like `SELECT [list of cols] FROM  table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.col2 = t1.col2`